# Microsoft.WebApplication.targets + Disable_CopyWebApplication=True doesn't prevent a csproj from creating a _PublishedWebsites folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild

Got a dummy project + a console project which apply xslt transformations so they employ Microsoft.WebApplication.targets in their respective .csproj files like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{39560935-7551-4789-9666-4A48AD0FE3C7}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>...</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>...</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    **<Disable_CopyWebApplication>True</Disable_CopyWebApplication>**
</PropertyGroup>
[...]
<PropertyGroup>
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(VSToolsPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command=".\.nuget\nuget.exe restore .\packages.config -PackagesDirectory .\..\packages" />
  <Delete Files="Config\ConnectionStrings\ConnectionStrings.config" />
  <Message Text="=====================================================================================================================================================" />
  <Message Text="Applying XSLT transformations (Disable_CopyWebApplication='$(Disable_CopyWebApplication)') using 'Microsoft.WebApplication.targets' from:" />
  <Message Text="" />
  <Message Text="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
  <Message Text="" />
  <TransformXml Source="Config\ConnectionStrings\ConnectionStrings.base.config" Transform="Config\ConnectionStrings\ConnectionStrings.$(Configuration.Replace('dbg@', '').Replace('rls@', '')).config" Destination="Config\ConnectionStrings\ConnectionStrings.config" />
  <Message Text="=====================================================================================================================================================" />
</Target>
```

To generate production builds for said projects in our build server we build them like so:

```
<MSBuild    Projects="$(_solutionFile)"
            Targets="$(TargetProject)"
            Properties="Platform=$(Platform);OutputPath=$(PublishUrl);Configuration=$(Configuration);"
            ToolsVersion="15.0"
/>
```

As shown above we employ

```
<Disable_CopyWebApplication>True</Disable_CopyWebApplication>
```

Still the _PublishedWebsite folder does get created anyways. What could we be missing here?

**UPDATE**

According to the debugging statements we placed in our .csproj file the "Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" which gets employed during the build is this one:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
```

The internal task which copies the "website" (exe in our case) is this:

```
<Target Name="_CopyWebApplication"
        Condition="!$(Disable_CopyWebApplication) And '$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'"
        DependsOnTargets="$(_CopyWebApplicationDependsOn)">

  <CallTarget Condition="'$(OnAfter_CopyWebApplication)' != ''" Targets="$(OnAfter_CopyWebApplication)" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />

</Target>
```

This task appears to be working as intended because it turns out that _PublishedWebsite **doesn't** contain **any** of the compiled dlls of the exe-project. **It contains only the roslyn dlls/exes with the following folder structure**:

```
 <Project_Output_Folder>\_PublishedWebsites\<Project.Name.Here>\bin\roslyn
```

I take it that the inclusion of the nuget packages:

```
 Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

and/or

```
 Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

is what's causing the problem. The nuget packages being used are these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net471" allowedVersions="[6.2.0]" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net471" allowedVersions="[1.0.8]" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.6.1" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" allowedVersions="[2.6.1]" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net471" allowedVersions="[10.0.3]" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="12.2.1100" targetFramework="net471" allowedVersions="[12.2.1100]" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" version="12.2.1100" targetFramework="net471" allowedVersions="[12.2.1100]" />
  <package id="StructureMap" version="4.6.1" targetFramework="net471" allowedVersions="[4.6.1]" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" allowedVersions="[4.3.0]" />
</packages>
```

**So I guess the question boils down to how can one make the Compilers package respect the dont-copy flag we are setting?**

Comment: According to the target `_CopyWebApplication` in the `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`: `<Target Name="_CopyWebApplication" Condition="'$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'" >`
So when Team Build sets `OutDir` or `OutputPath` explicitely this Condition evaluates to true and the copy runs. To verify this issue, you can not specify the OutputPath. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ec642ad-2e6d-424c-891a-62f6409da62a/how-to-prevent-msbuild-from-publishing-a-web-site?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: Thank you so much for tuning in. I have updated my answer to have it mention which Microsoft.WebApplication.targets we are using and how <Target Name="_CopyWebApplication"> is implemented. After reviewing the contents of the bin folder I came to realize that the culprit was the Compilers package. Any insight appreciated.